# Move camera offset phaser

Tags: javascript, scroll, 2d, editor, phaser-framework

I would like the camera to move to a specific offSetX. Using the method  "horizontalCamera.setScroll(800,0)" it moves instantly. How can I make it move with an animation?
P.S. I'm using phaser editor 2d

```
class GoNext extends UserComponent {

    constructor(gameObject) {
        super(gameObject);

        this.gameObject = gameObject;
        gameObject["__GoNext"] = this;

        /* START-USER-CTR-CODE */
        // Write your code here.
        /* END-USER-CTR-CODE */
    }

    /** @returns {GoNext} */
    static getComponent(gameObject) {
        return gameObject["__GoNext"];
    }

    /** @type {Phaser.GameObjects.Text} */
    gameObject;

    /* START-USER-CODE */
    awake() {
        let horizontalCamera
        this.gameObject.setInteractive().on("pointerdown", () => {
            horizontalCamera = this.scene.cameras.add(0, 0, 800, 600)
            horizontalCamera.setScroll(800, 0)
        });
    }
    // Write your code here.

    /* END-USER-CODE */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ***pan*** to a specific position, you can use the function `pan` [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Cameras.Scene2D.Camera.html#pan__anchor)

```js
   // moves the camera to the position (800,0) in 1000 ms
   this.cameras.main.pan(800, 0, 1000);
```

Check out [this official demo](https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src/camera/pan%20to.js), for a usable demo.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can "tween" the camera.

Something like this:

```js
this.add.tween({
    targets: this.cameras.main,
    scrollX: x,
    scrollY: y
});
```